# Copy a single file to a new folder in node js

Tags: node.js

I need a method to copy a single file to a new folder.
I have tried using `stream`, but it can’t copy a file to an empty folder.

Comment: provide some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default node js stream for copying file requires you to have the target directory, try to use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)